# How are you deploying blazor wasm grpc-web apps to azure?

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, blazor, grpc-web, webassembly

I am new to blazor wasm. I re-tooled a sample weather forecast stub to use blazor wasm/grpc-web/identityserver4 (google auth)/postgres db backend via dapper.

If i run it locally via visual studio 2019 then it works, but when I tried using azure continuous delivery using Azure App Service (new to this as well.. haha), it copied the artifacts but the web app never starts. I was thinking maybe I need some command to start app.server.exe so tried running it from the azure's web (terminal/console) manually and that too did not help.

I then tried using visual studio 2019's publish feature, that immediately said grpc is not supported. I am using grpc-web, so I am not sure.

I've setup ssl certificate etc on azure, so errors related to identity server etc are not there.

Anyways, how are you all deploying this combination (blazor wasm/grpc-web) combination to azure/heroku or whatever host you have chosen? Thanks for your help in advance.

Thanks,
Arjun

Comment: Have you succeeded to deploy it to azure using Visual Studio's [publish function](https://timheuer.com/blog/deploy-blazor-webassembly-applications-on-azure-using-github-actions-wasm/#azure-app-service-(windows)) locally?

Comment: Yes, it does work on my local IIS. Maybe I should try on another desktop where not many things are installed. Maybe I have some .net core stuff installed on this machine which may not be there on iis on azure. I did add .net core sdk via tasks in azure... will try again and see.

Comment: Figured it out. Somehow my app was not able to read Authentication/Authorization>Google Authentication Settings from the app. I hardcoded the client Id and Client Secret and now it works. I need to now figure out why it does not read those values from Azure settings. I'll close this question. I realized I do not know how to close a question in stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Glad to know you've figured it out. You can [add it as self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or [delete it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).